# Blobstore reader won't read large images

Tags: google-app-engine, go, blobstore

I am trying to read images from the Blobstore from the Go server side code. But if the image is large (as in: 0.5MB - 1.7MB) a large portion of the byte buffer becomes 0 which breaks the image.

The image works if I use serveUrl, but this is not an option for me in this case.

My first thought was that there was a size limit to the read, [found this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/#Go_Quotas_and_limits):

> In addition to systemwide safety quotas, a limit applies specifically
>   to the use of the Blobstore: the maximum size of Blobstore data that
>   can be read by the application with one API call is 32 megabytes.

The images I read are nowhere near 32MB.

Function I use to read from the Blobstore:

```
func BlobAsBase64(c appengine.Context, blobKey string) (*blobstore.BlobInfo, string, error) {
    info, err := blobstore.Stat(c, appengine.BlobKey(blobKey))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, "", err
    }

    imageBuffer := make([]byte, info.Size)
    reader := blobstore.NewReader(c, appengine.BlobKey(blobKey))
    if _, err = reader.Read(imageBuffer); err != nil {
        return nil, "", err
    }

    imageBase64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(imageBuffer)

    return info, imageBase64, nil
}
```

What is the reason that my images become broken when I read them from the Blobstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I conjecture the reason this isn't working is because the `reader.Read` method is returning before it has filled the buffer.  See the contract for [io.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes
>   read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read
>   returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the
>   call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read
>   conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

Note the last sentence in particular.

Instead of `reader.Read(imageBuffer)` try using [ioutil.ReadAll](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) which should fix your problem.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem! You rock! Thank you! :)